# Can't click to allow giving permissions

Tags: macos, permission

For many apps, I can't give them permissions. This prompt pops up

[image]

But I when I click on it, both buttons don't do anything, and it just stays there, until I restart the computer.

I've read that this could be due do some apps having control of the screen, and I've disabled both amethyst and hammerspoon, but the prompt stays there. I also cannot manually give Emacs permission, since Emacs doesn't show up under Security and Privacy, under the Reminders section.

I believe I started having issues after the previous system update.

The problem is the same as what is described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253120282) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/v2eh8a/running_m1_pro_mbp_security_prompts_cannot_be/)

What is the cause of this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does the issue persist if you start your Mac in Safe Mode (see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac)?

Comment: How did you install the editor? It depends on what code is running to get you an answer…

Comment: I've restarted in Safe Mode, and it finally worked, though I would like to know the reason for the error so I don't need to restart every time to give permission. I installed the software through a brew cask.

Comment: Safe mode rebuilds some caches and disables many third party extensions. Can you remove and add it now after a normal restart?

Comment: I've received another permissions prompt today, and the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only solution is to wait for apple to fix the bug.  A solution to getting rid of the dialogue was posted [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253997585), by going to Activity Monitor and killing the process. Then, the permissions can be manually given by going to System Preferences. Unfortunately, this process will have to be repeated for each time permissions are requested.

Answer (score 0):

Blubbler, I seemed to solve this issue accidentally. This is my own [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443728/406217) on my own question of this same issue

> I got the same macbook again on a deal & returned the old macbook. In the migration, the issue seems to have gone away. I migrated via time machine backup.

> So it seems, to permanently fix this issue, you can try reinstalling monterey. Or, if that fails, factory reset monterey & restore from a time machine backup.